# Folder structure in Test module

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I am new in Spring and Testing as well. I have question about folder structure in Spring Boot project for Test module.

Is following project structure ok for Integration and unit tests in Test module? Or what is the best practice for that? Thanks.

```
project/
├── main
└── test
    ├── integration
    │   └── SomeTestIT.java
    └── unit
        └── SomeTestU.java
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Spring and Spring Boot don't have specific recommendations about the test classes layout.

So instead, you should follow the conventions of your build tool, probably Gradle or Maven.
For them, `src/test/java` is designed to contain test classes to execute.
Just keep it.

You could have both unit and integration tests inside this directory and make the difference between them with a suffix : `Test` for unit tests and `IT` for integration tests.
These are the Maven conventions for [unit tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) and [integration tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).
By sticking to them, you would have much less effort to setup the tests facilities.

**Surefire (unit test)** :

> Inclusions
>
> By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test
>   classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> `"**/Test*.java"` - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java
>   filenames that start with "Test".
>
> `"**/*Test.java"` - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java
>   filenames that end with "Test".
>
> `"**/*Tests.java"` - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java
>   filenames that end with "Tests".
>
> `"**/*TestCase.java"` - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java
>   filenames that end with "TestCase".

**Failsafe Plugin (integration test)**  :

> Inclusions
>
> By default, the Failsafe Plugin will automatically include all test
>   classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> `"**/IT*.java"` - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java
>   filenames that start with "IT".
>
> `"**/*IT.java"` - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java
>   filenames that end with "IT".
>
> `"**/*ITCase.java"` - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java
>   filenames that end with "ITCase".